# delete a row conditionally using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file, which contains a specific number of sheets.

I want a python script to search the specified sheet for a value in the cell, and if found delete the entire row.

The script i have is currently built to search a row corresponding to a value and change the value.
I have tried modifying the script without any success.

This is my code:

```
import openpyxl
for f in files:
    if f[-4:] == "xlsx":
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
        sheet = book.active
        for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
            if row[0].value == "some_value":
                row[1].value = 1
        book.save(f)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Running on Python3, on PyCharm, on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: ***"I have tried modifying the script"***: [Edit] your question and show your attempt.

Comment: @yogeshsudheermodak Please check out my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to delete the row depending on the value condition:

```
import openpyxl

f = "testFile.xlsx"
if f[-4:] == "xlsx":
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    sheet = book.active
    [sheet.delete_rows(idx + 1) for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.values) if row[0] == "some value"]
    book.save(f)
```

OR

```
import openpyxl
f = "testFile.xlsx"
if f[-4:] == "xlsx":
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    sheet = book.active
    for idx,row in enumerate(sheet.values):
        if row[0] == "some value":
            sheet.delete_rows(idx+1)
    book.save(f)
```

Comment: The second one worked to perfection. Thanks so much.